# FeedComment Parent relationship

Tags: chatter, feeditem, schema

I have triggers on FeedItem and FeedComment where I need to dynamically read a field on their respective Parents (ParentId).

For FeedItem I can do (for example):

```
FeedItem.Parent.get('Name');
```

But for FeedComment, which seems analogous in most respects

```
FeedComment.Parent.get('Name');
```

does not work, and the Force.com IDE Schema doesn't seem to help me out.  Is there no way of getting for example the FeedComment Account Name without an SOQL query?

Comment: Have you tried going through the feed item. FeedComment is a child of FeedItem, which is the child of the record in question. So shouldn't it be FeedComment.FeedItem.Parent.get()?

Comment: FeedComment.FeedItem gives "Invalid foreign key relationship: FeedComment.FeedItem"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, I found that to get the Parent info in a trigger context I had to use an SOQL query.

But then, I found that even

```
FeedItem.Parent.get('Name');
```

doesn't work, since it is a polymorphic field.  See [here](http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/Apex-Code-Development/BUG-in-SOQL-Invalid-SOQL-to-get-Task-Owner-information/m-p/136496#M17680) for a description of the problem, and [here for a potential solution in the future](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000163431&language=en_US).

So, I use the method `FeedComment.ParentId.getSobjecttype()` to get the object to describe.  A complication is that the field to dynamically get may or may not be present in the org, and so I have to query non-statically, and catch any `QueryException` caused by the field not being present.  Not ideal, but it seems to work.